# My node and hub couldn't communicate with each other in selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-server

I download selenium-server-4.14.0 from official website and run it as hub on my machine (The operating system is window 11), I do the same on a virtual machine and run it as node (The operating system is window 10). When I register the node to the hub, my node keeps sending registration event and my hub keeps binding additional locator mechanisms: relative but the connection seems failed! Can you guys help me fix it?

[My hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnnTL.png)

[My node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vr17.png)

I try to find the solutions but found none!

Answer (score 0):

Your hub is listening on 192.168.56.1 at ports 4442 and 4443 but your node is reporting itself as accessible via 10.0.2.15 at port 5555.

Is that address accessible from the hub? Use curl or powershell tnc to test the accessibility. For curl, use "curl [http://10.0.2.15:5555/status"](http://10.0.2.15:5555/status%22) (for Se v4).

You may need to use the "--host" parameter to specific that node listen on a different interface.